# Issue displaying entries from a database

Tags: android, database

Here is a database base on SQLite in Andoird for a survey application. Each survey taken is a record which is stored in the database.

I have successfully created the database (and the database exists - I used an SQLite browser to go through all the different records).

However, I have an issue displaying the all the records after a few surveys are taken. Only the first survey will be displayed in the activity. No other record will be displayed even though they exist in the memory. Is something wrong with my simple cursor adapter?

Here's my database class:

```
package nidhin.survey;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Database extends Activity {
    private static final SimpleCursorAdapter SimpleCursorAdapter = null;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.database);

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        lv.setClickable(true);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent intent=new Intent(Database.this,MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
         });


        Intent sender=getIntent();

        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Cursor c = dbh.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + 
                        DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME + 
                ", " + DatabaseHelper.VALUE1 + 
                ", " + DatabaseHelper.VALUE2 + 
                " FROM " +
                DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null); // initializing 

        String[] dataFrom ={DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME, DatabaseHelper.VALUE1, DatabaseHelper.VALUE2};//, DatabaseHelper.VALUE3, DatabaseHelper.VALUE4, DatabaseHelper.VALUE5, DatabaseHelper.VALUE6, DatabaseHelper.VALUE7, DatabaseHelper.VALUE8, DatabaseHelper.VALUE9, DatabaseHelper.VALUE10, DatabaseHelper.VALUE11};
        int[] dataTo = {R.id.name, R.id.value1, R.id.value2};//, R.id.value3, R.id.value4, R.id.value5, R.id.value6, R.id.value7, R.id.value8, R.id.value9, R.id.value10, R.id.value11};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.row, c, dataFrom, dataTo);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onListItemClick()
    {

    }


}
```

And the database helper:

```
package nidhin.survey;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String TABLE_NAME = "mygrades";
static final String COL_NAME = "name";
static final String VALUE1 = "ClassNumber";
static final String VALUE2 = "value2";
static final String VALUE3 = "value3";
static final String VALUE4 = "value4";
static final String VALUE5 = "value5";
static final String VALUE6 = "value6";
static final String VALUE7 = "value7";
static final String VALUE8 = "value8";
static final String VALUE9 = "value9";
static final String VALUE10 = "value10";
static final String VALUE11 = "value11";


DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, "grades.sqlite", null, 20);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
               "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
               COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + 
               VALUE1 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE2 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE3 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE4 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE5 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE6 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE7 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE8 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE9 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE10 + " TEXT, " +
               VALUE11 + " TEXT);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    android.util.Log.w("cars", "Upgrading database, all table info will be lost");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Comment: May be you are updating the same record instead of inserting new record?? have you checked the records in the Database? you can find the database at
/data/data/YOUR PACKAGE NAME/databases/DB NAME.db

Comment: Didn't you said on your previous question that you solved the problem?

Comment: @slukian , i thought that the table was not being created , but i did create the table. the issue was in the XML file where i had to properly define how to appropriately display the textviews ( the three columns )

Comment: @Ahmed I did check the database record and I am indeed inserting a new record rather than updating the entry . I checked the table using SQLite database browser

Comment: does my  simple cursor adapter have to do with this? its only displaying the first record

Comment: See my answer, try cursor.moveToFirst()

Comment: You are only retrieving one record.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets try this again**

Try this:

In your database helper (notice there should be 5 nulls):

```
public Cursor fetchAllSurveys() {
    return mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "_id", COL_NAME, VALUE1,VALUE2 }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

In your onCreate it would be used like this:

```
Cursor c = dbh.fetchAllSurveys();
String[] dataFrom ={DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME, DatabaseHelper.VALUE1, DatabaseHelper.VALUE2};
int[] dataTo = {R.id.name, R.id.value1, R.id.value2};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c, dataFrom, dataTo); 
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is member rank and status?

Comment: I see that you have 5 columns MEMBER_ROWID,
            MEMBER_LAST, MEMBER_FIRST, MEMBER_RANK, MEMBER_STATUS ; But i have only 3 columns

Comment: This is what I did      public Cursor fetchAllMembers() {
      SQLiteDatabase db;
      
         return db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME,DatabaseHelper.VALUE1,
           DatabaseHelper.VALUE2 }, null,
                 null,null);
     }

Comment: You are missing a couple of nulls in that call.  I've edited my answer, hopefully that will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Call the Cursor.moveToFirst, like:

```
if (c !=null)
{
    c.moveToFirst();
}
```

Before assigning this line:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.row, c, dataFrom, dataTo);
```

Comment: this statement moves c to the first line right? But we would want to retrieve all records right?

Comment: I tried and put it before simple adapter  line just like u said , but still the same :-(

Comment: Can you check that how many record are returned by the cursor by using:
c.getCount()??